# iMacros how to remove GBP £ symbol from extracted variable

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have a problem trying to extract £ gbp symbols from extracted values in imacros, I am not sure why its not working, but any advise on how to fix it would be very useful thanks in advance for looking

the value extracted would be in the format £19.99 and I am looking to trim off the £ to just have 19.99

the commented out line seems to pop up a alert with the £ value removed, but in imacros the extracted value is still £19.99

```
VERSION BUILD=8070701 RECORDER=CR

TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:prcIsum EXTRACT=TXT
'SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; x=s.replace(\"£\",\"\"); alert(x);")
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; x=s.replace(\"£\",\"\"); x;")
' in order to see the extracted value use 'PROMPT''
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
```